# sun jna library with support for arm 64

Tags: jna

Where can I get a JNA library with support for ARM64? The com.sun.jna_4.jar includes the native libjnidispatch.so library for ARM, but not for ARM64.

I'm getting an exception saying:

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native library
(com/sun/jna/linux-aarch64/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path.
```

Comment: You can build it yourself with the `ant native` target (assuming you have a build environment on your ARM64 system).

Answer (score 1):

Download the android-aarch64.aar file from below link,
https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/tree/master/lib/native

Unzip it, you will get libjnidispatch.so.

In your App jniLibs folder, create a folder /arm64-v8a and put the .so file there.
jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libjnidispatch.so